# crash with empty <Text> node when using marginVertical

Tags: windows, react-native

There is a crash in react-native-windows 0.47 when a text element is empty and marginVertical is used:

```
render() {
  var foo = null;

  return <Text style={marginVertical: 0}>
    foo
  </Text>;
}
```

The crash is in ReactTextShadowNode::MeasureText(), where the supplied height is a negative number. Note in the real example its a real application -- this is a condensed example to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Eric Rozell, this is a bug in Yoga that was first worked around in React Native 0.24 Android [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.24-stable/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/text/ReactTextShadowNode.java#L208) and is still present in React Native 0.50 on Android.

I'll update this answer once a similar work around is published in a React Native Windows release. The [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/1429) is filed in the React Native Windows GitHub project

In the meantime, add a null/undefined check for the content of the Text node and return an alternate `<Text />` that doesn't include the `marginVertical` style.